# How can I get the value of an input element instead of `null`?

Tags: javascript, html

When the user inputs any number, the number needs to be joined with the assigned text (in this case a URL). However it results in this: `http://someurl.com/?value=null`. Instead of `null` I expect the number the user inputted.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var juarel = "http://someurl.com/?value=";
    var velju = document.getElementById('somenumber');
    var rezon = juarel.concat(velju);

    function print() {
      alert(rezon);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="somenumber" value="">
    <button type="button" id="submit" name="button" onclick="print()">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: [You want to use `juarel.concat(velju.value)` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the correct value from the HTML element calling `.value`. Then put the code to retrieve the value inside the function, otherwise you are reading the value at the beginning, and the element is empty. You have to read the value when you press the button:

```html
<body>
<form>

<input type="number" id="somenumber" value="">
<button type="button" id="submit" name="button" 
onclick="print()">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">



function print () {
  var juarel = "http://someurl.com/?value=";
  var velju = document.getElementById('somenumber').value;

  var rezon = juarel.concat(velju);
  alert(rezon);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This works with the addition of value property after getElementById. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome but there is also in my code the `.value`

Comment: Yes there is, but since I haven't copied your code but altered mine I had to add it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1st use `.value` as `var velju = document.getElementById('somenumber').value`

2nd wrap those into the function, so when you click, you get the current value, otherwise, it is always undefined since it is called on init.

```
  function print() {
    var juarel = "http://someurl.com/?value=";
    var velju = document.getElementById('somenumber').value;
    var rezon = juarel.concat(velju);
    alert(rezon);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function print() {
    var juarel = "http://someurl.com/?value=";
    var velju = document.getElementById('somenumber').value;
    var rezon = juarel.concat(velju);
    alert(rezon);
  }
</script>


<body>
  <form>

    <input type="number" id="somenumber" value="">
    <button type="button" id="submit" name="button" onclick="print()">SUBMIT</button>

  </form>
```